# Resize image from +1mb taken from camera intent to <=150k Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am trying to reduce the size of picture taken from camera and gallery (1+mb to 150k. both).

1. code to take photo:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

   //intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

   intent.putExtra("outputX", 50);

   intent.putExtra("outputY", 50);

   intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);

   intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

   intent.putExtra("outputX", 128);

   intent.putExtra("outputY", 128);

   intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

   intent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

   intent.putExtra("return-data", false);

   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));

   startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
   ```
2. intent to select from gallery

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

   intent.setType("image/*");

   //intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

   intent.putExtra("outputX", 50);

   intent.putExtra("outputY", 50);

   intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);

   intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

   intent.putExtra("scale", true); 

   intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,destination);
   intent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choisir Photo"),SELECT_FILE);
   ```

My activity result is as follows

```
@Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == PICTURE_RESULT) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

                Editer.PHOTO_FROM=11;

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString());

                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                        f = temp;

                        break;

                    }

                }

                //Uri.fromFile(createFile());

                Constant.filePath=f.getAbsolutePath();

                String fname = "user_image_golf.jpg";

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

                options.inSampleSize = 4;

                options.outWidth = 100;

                options.outHeight = 100;

                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                File myDir = new File(root + "user_image_golf.jpg");   // == /
                myDir.mkdirs();

                destination = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"user_image_golf.jpg");


                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(destination.toString(), options);

                Bitmap map = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao);

                //byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

                File file = new File (myDir, f.getAbsolutePath());

                if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();

                try {

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, out);

                    out.flush();

                    out.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("//imagedata=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);");

                ///imagedata=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                //rotateImage(Uri.fromFile(destination).toString());

            }


            else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                Constant.filePath =selectedImageUri.toString();

                Editer.PHOTO_FROM=2;

                System.out.println("getAbsolutePath() "+selectedImageUri);

                System.out.println("selectedImageUri-getAbsolutePath()
 "+getPath(selectedImageUri,m));


            }

        }
        m.finish();

    }
```

If i select a photo from gallery or take a picture from camera, the new photo from camera or latest selected image from gallery should override the photo saved on sd card.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Comment: why do you have a loop to search for a file instead of `f = new File(f, "temp.jpg");` directly?

Comment: nota : PNG is lossless in android. the quality parameter is ignored. Use JPG is you need to reduce the size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BVMobile.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                // folder stuff
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File imagesFolder = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "verificationapp");
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();

                Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                tempfile = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                        .format(alsoNow);
                File image = new File(imagesFolder, tempfile + ".png");
                Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            if (data != null) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                selectedfile = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

                Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                        .format(alsoNow);

                imgname = currentdate + "_" + refid;

                    strPhoto1 = SERVER_FILE_PATH + imgname + ".png";




            }
        }  else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            File imagesFolder = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "verificationapp");
            File image = new File(imagesFolder, tempfile + ".png");
            selectedfile = image.toString();

            imgname = tempfile + "_" + refid;

        }
    }
}

public String converttobase64(String picturePath) {
    String b64 = null;
    if (!picturePath.equals("")) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);

        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        b64 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }

    return b64;
}
```